# devtools::install_github with proxy PAC file

Tags: r, devtools

Is there a way to configure `install_github()` to accommodate a PAC file? I don't just have a single host:port and I have no username:password information so `set_config` from `httr` doesn't work. I'm on Windows.

```
> install_github("hadley/dplyr")
Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) : 
  Couldn't connect to server
> traceback()
12: .Call(R_curl_fetch_disk, url, handle, path, "wb", nonblocking)
11: curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle)
10: request_fetch.write_disk(req$output, req$url, handle)
9: request_fetch(req$output, req$url, handle)
8: request_perform(req, hu$handle$handle)
7: httr::GET(url, path = path, httr::write_disk(path = tmp))
6: remote_package_name.github_remote(remote)
5: remote_package_name(remote)
4: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
3: vapply(remotes, install_remote, ..., FUN.VALUE = logical(1))
2: install_remotes(remotes, quiet = quiet, ...)
1: install_github("hadley/dplyr")
```